# The length of the first and last names

Tags: contact, fields, object, setup

There is a `Name` field of type Name in Contact object. It consists of `FirstName` and `LastName`. I can query those two fields using Apex.

Even though I cannot find any proofs in Object Manager of that, I am sure that `FirstName` and `LastName` have Text type.

Now I would like to know how many characters they accept (i.e. if their type is Text(n) I would like to know what value does n have). I tried to use Object Manager to find that out, but there seems to be no info about this. And also, when I go to edition of Name field it tells you nothing useful on `FirstName` and `LastName` fields.

So, what is the length of `FirstName` and `LastName` fields?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quicker way to do that is to use describe call in Apex.

```
System.debug(Contact.FirstName.getDescribe().length); //Prints 40
System.debug(Contact.LastName.getDescribe().length); //Prints 80
```

It also works for All fields standard and custom.

That being said, you can use global describe to get lengths of all fields.

Src : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm

Answer (score 6):

you can check details about fields on [Contact SOAP API guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm)

FirstName - The contact’s first name up to **40 characters**.

LastName - Required. Last name of the contact up to **80 characters**.